# ClassNotFoundException on PhoneGap Getting Started with Android

Tags: android, cordova

I followed the PhoneGap Getting Started with Android instructions.  The only thing that isn't exactly as described in the steps is that I have cordova version 2.1.0.  The application builds and installs on my phone, but gives a ClassNotFoundException just after starting.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.phonegaptest/com.example.phonegaptest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.phonegaptest.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.phonegaptest-2.apk]

The MainActivity is the only class in the application.  Why can't it be found?

Update:
Here's my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What does your AndroidManifest.xml look like? That is probably where the problem lies.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this, but I don't like the solution.  I went into the Eclipse Build Path settings for the project, and checked the boxes to export the three jars the project depends on.  This solved the problem.  Then I started unchecking them to figure out which one I really needed to do that for, and after unchecking all of the boxes, the program still runs.

Comment: +1 , I was facing this issue when updated my ADT to v22. My all phone-gap projects stop working. After doing as what you suggested, my application starts working again, Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes you could fix this by reordering the lib import list. I made with cordova on the top and it just works. Pretty weird solution anyway.

Comment: your solution worked for me also, but partially. your application is still working after unchecking the checkbox, mine wasn't. not sure if it will cause any problem in the future.

Comment: Moving the cordova jar to the top in Order and Export solved it for me!

Answer (score -1):

i was also facing similar situation after i upgraded to v22, when i added the jar file to the build path it started working